# How to add Java long suffix l

Tags: java, types, timestamp, long-integer

I'm actually struggling on how to add the "L" suffix to a long value.

A JSON services provides me with timestamps in seconds. In my output I would like to bring that bunch of seconds in some kind of a readable format.
Therefore I would like to use SimpleDateFormat, which needs to have a timestamp in milliseconds.

So I've got the value 1545151800 which is in seconds.
To bring i into milliseconds it would be (*1000) 1545151800000

Because it's a long, it should have the value 1545151800000L.

How can I accomplish to add the "L" to my value? It's not possible to add some chars to a long.
If I don't care about the "L" suffix I get different (wrong) results.

Comment: multiply by `1000L`

Comment: In the general case, if you have an `int` value (`x`) and you want a `long` value, you can cast it: `(long)x`. But if you're doing something like multiplying by another value, since `int * long` results in a `long`, you can do `x * 1000L`.

Comment: The `L` is only for Java code and doesn't do anything at runtime. As you say, a `long` doesn't have a char so it doesn't make any sense. however an `int * int` is an `int` so this value can overflow. If you do `int * long` the result is a `long` which might not overflow in your case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've already got a long, but missing the last three digits, so `x * 1000L` would have also been my suggestion.
The problem is, that `SimpleDateFormat` still doesn't recognize my timestamp.

Comment: Here is my code for SimpleDateFormat:
`@XmlElement(name="dt")
 long timeOfData;
 
 long timeOfDataL = timeOfData*1000L;
 String humanTimeOfData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US).format(new Date(timeOfDataL));`

Comment: This  `1545151800 ` should be `2018-12-18T16:50:00+00:00`

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, that's the output I expect. But I can't achieve that because SimpleDateFormat needs the input long in Milliseconds which I haven't got and need to convert it.

Comment: Also, you ought to be looking at `Instant.ofEpochSecond`.

Comment: @pbur - In the code you've shown, if `timeOfData` actually gets the value `1545151800`, [it works for me](https://ideone.com/JnSWtJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got a solution. The problem wasn't the suffix thing like T.J. Crowder pointed out.
It had to do with my JAXB and json service.

[Before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhnTu.png)

After putting the two lines into my toString() method, everything worked fine. timeOfDataL was already utilized while timeOfData was still 0. So 0 leaded to 01/01/1970

[After fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwlhb.png)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your finding and your fix. Only don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). As a minor point it can even convert directly from seconds since the epoch and save you the multiplication by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    String humanDateOfData = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timeOfData)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(dateFormatter);
```

You may declare the date formatter just once in your class rather than creating a new one for each call to `toString`:

```
static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.US);
```

On my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone this gave a `humanDateOfData` of `18/12/2018` that you may now use in the return value from `toString`.

In this case the is code longer than the code you have, but I still warmly recommend it. The date and time classes that you were using, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are poorly designed, the latter notoriously troublesome. They are also long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API that came out in 2014. Also, while multiplying by 1000 may seem simple, doing your own time conversions is very often complex and error-prone, so it’s a bad habit to get into. `Instant` directly accepts seconds since the epoch, so it’s no longer needed. Finally the modern code makes it explicit that a time zone is used for deciding the date, I like that. If you know the time zone, you may also specify which one, like for example `ZoneId.of("Asia/Harbin")`.

**Lonk:** [Oracle Tutotial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)